# Big O / Logarithmic Equivalency

Tags: asymptotics

In one of the algorithms textbooks I was reading, it states that $O(3^{\log_2n})$ can be rewritten as $O(n^{\log_23})$. Why is this the case?

Comment: Please note that you are able to [accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and also to upvote answers you think have shown effort and are helpful. (Not just answers to your own questions but also others on the site.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall the following log rule:

> $$\log_2 (x^k) = (k)(\log_2 x) \tag{1}$$

Now to prove that $3^{\log_2 n} = n^{\log_2 3}$, it suffices to prove that their logs (base $2$) are equal. Indeed, observe that:
\begin{align*}
\log_2(3^{\log_2 n})
&= (\log_2 n)(\log_2 3) &\text{by (1), where $x = 3$ and $k = \log_2 n$} \\
&= (\log_2 3)(\log_2 n) &\text{by the commutativity of multiplication} \\
&= \log_2(n^{\log_2 3}) &\text{by (1), where $x = n$ and $k = \log_2 3$} \\
\end{align*}
as desired. $~~\blacksquare$

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

$\textbf{Hint}: x^{\log_by}=y^{\log_b x}$